# multiple update queries on single field in if statements on single form submit

Tags: php, mysql, forms

What i am doing:

I have provided the progress bar to the user which increases or decreases as the user fills/empties the fields in the form by +/- 10%, which gets updated to the database when user submits the form. This progress bar intimates the user that how much percentage profile of the user is completed.

What problem i am facing:

I have provided multiple update queries which runs whenever whenever it satisfies if statement. All of the if statements and queries are working as i have already checked that. But the value of progress bar field in database is only updating **once**, either it increases when user fills the field or decreases when user empties the field. 
What if user updates in all fields in that case also it is increasing or decreasing by 10%

Here is my code:

```
<?
 include('includes/include.inc.php');
 protect_seeker_page();

 $loginLine=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query
      ("select * from tb_user_login where   user_login_id='$_SESSION[SEEKER_ID]'"));
 $userLine=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query
      ("select * from tb_user where user_login_id='$_SESSION[SEEKER_ID]'"));
 $metadataLine=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query
      ("select * from tb_user_metadata where user_login_id='$_SESSION[SEEKER_ID]'"));


  $company=$userLine['user_progress']+10;
  $company2=$userLine['user_progress']-10;

  $skill=$userLine['user_progress']+10;
  $skill2=$userLine['user_progress']-10;

  $ind=$userLine['user_progress']+10;
  $ind2=$userLine['user_progress']-10;


  $resume=$userLine['user_progress']+10;
  $resume2=$userLine['user_progress']-10;

  if($_POST['Submit']=='Update'){

 if($userLine['user_company_name']=="" and $_POST['user_company_name']!=""){
 mysql_query
     ("update tb_user set user_progress='".$company."' 
         where user_login_id='$_SESSION[SEEKER_ID]'"); }

    if($userLine['user_skills_id']=="" and $_POST['user_skills']!="")
      {
 mysql_query("update tb_user set user_progress='".$skill."' 
      where user_login_id='$_SESSION[SEEKER_ID]'"); }

    if($userLine['user_resume_title']=="" and $_POST['user_resume_title']!=""){
 mysql_query("update tb_user set user_progress='".$resume."' 
      where user_login_id='$_SESSION[SEEKER_ID]'"); }
 if($userLine['user_industry_id']==0 and $_POST['industry_name']!=""){
echo mysql_query("update tb_user set user_progress='".$ind."' 
      where user_login_id='$_SESSION[SEEKER_ID]'"); }




if($_POST['user_company_name']=="" and $userLine['user_company_name']!=""){
mysql_query("update tb_user set user_progress='".$company2."' 
    where user_login_id='$_SESSION[SEEKER_ID]'");   }

if($_POST['user_skills']=="" and $userLine['user_skills_id']!=""){
    mysql_query("update tb_user set user_progress='".$skill2."' 
      where user_login_id='$_SESSION[SEEKER_ID]'"); }

if($_POST['user_resume_title']=="" and $userLine['user_resume_title']!=""){
mysql_query("update tb_user set user_progress='".$resume2."'
          where user_login_id='$_SESSION[SEEKER_ID]'"); }
if($_POST['industry_name']=="" and $userLine['user_industry_id']!=0){
mysql_query("update tb_user set user_progress='".$ind2."'
         where user_login_id='$_SESSION[SEEKER_ID]'");  }



        }


       ?>
```

Comment: can you elaborate your question much more? as it not clearing the all things

Comment: i think you can use case here

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ In this code all my update queries are working but it is  
still not only changing the value by +/- 10 on single submit even if the value become +/- 20 or +/- 30 or +/- 40

Comment: @Prafulla is there any use of `case` even if all the `if statements` are working correctly

Comment: @Sonam miss use the below code that I have post in the answer. this will work for you.

Comment: @Sonam I'm not sure as i told you before... and after u explaining your issue with brokeheart your problem is not what i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
$progress = $userLine['user_progress'];

  if($_POST['Submit']=='Update'){

  if($userLine['user_company_name']=="" and $_POST['user_company_name']!=""){
     $progress +=10;
  }

  if($userLine['user_skills_id']=="" and $_POST['user_skills']!=""){
     $progress +=10;
  }

  if($userLine['user_resume_title']=="" and $_POST['user_resume_title']!=""){
      $progress +=10;
  }
  if($userLine['user_industry_id']==0 and $_POST['industry_name']!=""){
      $progress +=10; 
  }

  if($_POST['user_company_name']=="" and $userLine['user_company_name']!=""){
    $progress -=10;
  }

  if($_POST['user_skills']=="" and $userLine['user_skills_id']!=""){
     $progress -=10;
  }

  if($_POST['user_resume_title']=="" and $userLine['user_resume_title']!=""){
      $progress -=10;
  }
  if($_POST['industry_name']=="" and $userLine['user_industry_id']!=0){
     $progress -=10;
  }
  mysql_query("update tb_user set user_progress='".$progress."'
         where user_login_id='$_SESSION[SEEKER_ID]'");  
  }
```

In your code you are always adding the +/- 10 with current value of which is present in the table so it is always adding the +/-10 not +/- 20 and /-30 and so no. so you need to use it as I have suggest.

> Note: Do not use the mysql_* as it has been deprecate.
>            Always use the mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: @Sonam its really my pleasure to help you. My name is Gaurav. In future you can contact to me thru my blog. http://sugarcrmguide.blogspot.com/ check my blog.

Comment: This project is started by somebody else thats why i'm using `mysql_*` , else i always use `mysqli_*` 

Thank you for suggestion!